# Method to excute query and return results

Tags: android, sqlite

App won't run - trying to execute query to print certain value

Method:

```
public Cursor trying(String vg){
    String q="SELECT quantity FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS +  " WHERE name=" + vg;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor  cursor = db.rawQuery(q,null);

            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
            }
            return cursor;
    }
```

Calling method from main

```
Cursor wow = db.trying("gold");
text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView13);
text.setText((CharSequence) (wow));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first. Since you are directly adding trying variables into statement, variable must be wrapped to single quotes or it's interpeted as column.

```
"SELECT quantity FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS +  " WHERE name= '" + vg + "'";
```

And second "big" problem, look here:

```
text.setText((CharSequence) (wow));
```

Here you are trying to cast `Cursor` to `CharSequence` but it's not possible. If you want to retrieve data from `Cursor` you have to use one from the getters methods of Cursor class in your case **getString()** method:

```
String quantity = wow.getString(0); // it returns your quantity from Cursor
text.setText(quantity);
```

Now it should works.

### Recommendation:

I suggest you to an usage of *parametrized statements* which actually use **placeholders** in your queries. They provide much more safer way for adding and retrieving data to / from database.

Let's rewrite your code:

```
String q = "SELECT quantity FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS + " WHERE name = ?";
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor  cursor = db.rawQuery(q, new String[] {vg});
```

It works simply. Placeholder **`?`** will be replaced with your string value.

Comment: @user2062656 add here your logcat or kind of exception, please.

Comment: 04-05 20:36:19.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3200): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-05 20:36:19.968: E/AndroidRuntime(3200): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidhive.androidsqlite/com.androidhive.androidsqlite.AndroidAss2SQL}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Gold (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT quantity FROM coms1 WHERE name = Gold

Comment: its says that gold cannot be found but in logcat I saw it in the table :s

Comment: @user2062656 i mentioned you need to add single quotes. copy query from my answer or use second approach with placeholder that is more efficient and correct.

Comment: @user2062656 so you did it how i mentioned? Look at my code and copy and paste it please.